# Log the URI's path after 'proxy_pass' directive is processed

Tags: nginx, logging, proxy

I have a `proxy_pass` directive configured for some location in nginx config:

```
location /books/ {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8888/;
}
```

In the log I'd like to see the full URI my requests are proxied to.

Let's say, I send the request with `http://nginx/books/some-book` URI. The rule I've configured proxies this request to `http://localhost:8888/some-book` and this string is what I'd like to see in the log.

I've checked [HTTP Upstream module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) and [HTTP Proxy module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) docs, but couldn't find the variable that contains the URI after it is processed by `proxy_pass` directive.